# Version control system that works with branches and code tracking

Tags: version-control

Can I do the following without having to learn any version control systems?

- branch a codebase (to install an addon on each branch)
- merge files (merge--or rather--replace stock files with edited files if provided)
- merge files from different branches (so I can cherry-pick a combination of working addons)

I'm a user of [osCommerce e-commerce CMS](http://www.oscommerce.com). And it has an addon system which are patches for the stock codebase to increase functionality and features.

The addons site hosts packages which generally contain modified files to replace the stock files and instructions if the files in question have already been modified. I've found it difficult to keep track of changes I've been doing. And I couldn't just revert back to what it was before trying to install a new addon and edit a bunch of files.

I considered using version systems like Git or something but other than editing by following instructions, I don't do a single line of coding myself. I signed up for GitHub thinking that I could just graphically take care of versioning, merging, etc. on their website, but the web frontend lacked those abilities or they weren't obviously visible.

I already tried GitHub for Windows. I could ask it to clone the osCommerce repo (they develop on GitHub), and browsing to the repo it shows the last commit and diff. For the life of me I couldn't find anyway to do the bullet points I mentioned above.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programmers, and programming-related matters. If you ask this question here, you will get answers from a programmer's point of view - namely, use a standard source control system. It sounds like you don't want that; you might like to ask this question somewhere else, such as SuperUser, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). You would still have to get a grasp of git basics, but the interface is about as visual and user-friendly as it gets with VCS.

The [ProGit book](http://git-scm.com/book) is very good for git starters.

EDIT: to branch with SmartGit, you can use the `F7` shortcut, or go to the `branch` menu (in the middle of the options list on the very top). Select `new branch`, in the pop-up dialog, enter the name for your branch and select `Add Branch and Switch`. Voila, you have branched the codebase and the changes you make can be committed to the new branch.

You might not want to hear it (again), but for the single purpose of sparing you lots of frustration I too advise to read up some git basics. The first 60 pages of the GitPro book would be enough. Maybe less.

Even though VCS is not for code only, all current systems have been designed by programmers for programmers. Without some basic understanding of the inner workings, you will sometimes get unexpected results. Results you will have to recover from.

Comment: Thanks for the book link, but there are two reasons I don't want to learn git or any other VCS: 1. I myself am not writing any code; 2. For now, I'm using Windows, I don't want to go through the hassle of setting up those software. I can use, and am much more comfortable on, Linux terminals.

Comment: About SmartGit, it looks like it meets me requirements, but if you don't mind, I'll ask anyway: is there any open-source client with same features?

Comment: VC systems are not about code but rather about change management. It often makes sense to put things totally unrelated to code under version control. As to SmartGit, I'm afraid there is nothing really on par out there. But the free and open source clients [msysgit](http://msysgit.github.com/) and [tortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) are quite mature too.

Comment: Though I still can't find how to create a new, separate branch. (I want to separately apply different set of patches on the same base)

Comment: @Oxwivi - have added branching details to the answer

Answer (score 3):

GitHub does have those features.

Download [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) (or [Mac](http://mac.github.com/)) and use the graphical interface to your heart's desire. I don't use any GUI for Git (because it's easier to just run `git commit -a` then to open up a window and click buttons) but the GitHub interfaces for Mac and Windows look sleek.

In order to merge code via GitHub, you need to first create a branch of the original code that you will be modifying. This is called a fork. Once you are done with the changes and wish to merge them back into the main code, send a Pull Request back to the original repository and GitHub will merge them for you.

I'm not entirely sure how the UI's handle this, but they should be nice.

Comment: They only look nice. I've checked out GitHub for Windows already (don't own a Mac). See my edit for my question.

Comment: I'm not sure what else can help you. I've been using Git with and without GitHub for over three years now and it has worked exactly the way I wanted it to. The three bullet points that you outlined are the *core* purpose of Git and any other VCS: forking (branching) and merging.

Comment: I know those are the core purpose, but I don't want to figure out the git commands for doing those. As I'm not writing any code myself, I have to do those every once in a blue moon--so a simple button to do each of them would be really helpful.

Comment: So you're saying that the GitHub GUIs are completely useless? I find that *really* hard to believe.  What do they do if they don't do what Git is made to do?

Comment: Like I said in the question, "the web frontend lacked those abilities or they weren't obviously visible". I forked the repo from the project, great. Next, I can see existing branches made by the project, but I can't figure out how to create my own. Third, I found how to upload files but did not see anything that would allow me to merge files.

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand what you're dealing with. Forking and branching are not the same. To merge forks, you click "Send Pull Request" and accept it on the main project's branch.

Comment: That's the thing. It's not about contributing code, I want to maintain my own forks and combine them as necessary. But how come I can't have my own branches when clicking 'fork' separates into my own repo. Meh, knowledge about how git work itself is shallow.